# Retrieving a set of all Nth children

Tags: sql, mysql, ranking

The situation:

- MySQL 5.0
- 2 tables
- 1-to-many parent-child foreign key relationship (A.ID = B.PARENT_ID)

What's needed:

- A SELECT query that yields the set of all the Nth children (sorted by their IDs)
- Also need a form for use in UPDATE

Example:

Table B

```
| ID | PARENT_ID |
------------------
|  1 |     1     |
|  2 |     1     |
|  3 |     1     |
|  4 |     2     |
|  5 |     2     |
|  6 |     2     |
|  7 |     2     |
|  8 |     3     |
|  9 |     3     |
| 10 |     4     |
```

Desired Result Set for, e.g., all 2nd children

```
| A.ID | B.ID | B.PARENT_ID |
-----------------------------
|    1 |    2 |           1 |
|    2 |    5 |           2 |
|    3 |    9 |           3 |
```

Perhaps something to do with a feature of GROUP BY that I am not seeing?

My mind has totally become stuck seeing the solution to this problem procedurally. All help much appreciated.

Comment: I'd appreciate a vote more than granting the answer.  My comment is brazen, but with respect to the information provided and a valid, functional query.  And there's example data for anyone else who'd like to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don is correct - MySQL doesn't have ranking functionality.  But luckily, it does allow you to initialize & reference a variable so you can code the logic for ranking.

This will return the rows for the 2nd children:

```
SELECT x.aid,
       x.bid,
       x.parent_id
  FROM (SELECT a.id 'aid',
               b.id 'bid',
               b.parent_id,
               CASE WHEN b.parent_id = @parent_id THEN @rownum := @rownum +1 ELSE @rownum := 1 END AS rownum,
               @parent_id := b.parent_id
          FROM TABLE_A a
          JOIN TABLE_B b ON b.parent_id = a.id
          JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0, @parent_id := NULL) r
      ORDER BY b.parent_id, b.id) x
 WHERE x.rownum = 2
```

Change the `WHERE x.rownum = ?` to whatever Nth level children you want.  The `ORDER BY` in the subquery is important to make sure the ranking comes out properly.

It's not clear to me how you want to use this for an `UPDATE` query - provide more detail & I'll update to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not have a mechanism to do this Nth relation. Oracle has an extension and maybe others.

What is the context?

If you are building a HTML form for update, generate the data with for loop and put the ID's in the table for simple update upon submit.